# PHPExcel getHyperlinks by column

Tags: url, hyperlink, phpexcel

I convert excel files in HTML table with PHPEXcel, using Php5.3.13 and Symfony2.

That one work :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumn('N4')->hasHyperlink();
$url = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('N4')->getHyperlink()->getUrl();
$url = str_replace('../old/path', '/new/path', $url);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('N4')->getHyperlink()->setUrl($url);
```

**EDITED** : I just wanna do it on Column :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('N1:N9')->hasHyperlink();
$url = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('N1:N9')->getHyperlink()->getUrl();
$url = str_replace('old/path', '/new/path', $url);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('N1:N9')->getHyperlink()->setUrl($url);
```

Can you show me how to loop on getHyperlinkCollection(); result please ?

Thanks a lot ! @MarkBaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Worksheet object holds details of all the hyperlinks, and you can retrieve that information using

```
$sheet->getHyperlinkCollection();
```

This will return an array of hyperlink objects, indexed by cell address; and you could then use [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with an appropriate callback and the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` flag set to extract those within a specific range.

Comment: I use Php 5.3 so the flag parameter doesnt exist.. i have edited my post @MarkBaker

Comment: Can u show me how i loop on the result array ? @MarkBaker